# Provide input for constant argument count macro from variable argument count macro in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I want to define macro that will add prefixes to every argument that is not prefix.

I've defined some constant argument count macros and then defined one using variable arguments to invoke others. My problem is that varadic macro does not provide proper input for constant macros.

```
#define prefix2(pefixV, a1, a2) pefixV##a1, pefixV##a2
#define prefix3(pefixV, a1, a2, a3) prefix2(pefixV, x, y)##, ##pefixV##z

#define prefixX(count, pefixV, ...) prefix##count(pefixV, __VA_ARGS__)

//MacroTester from stackoverflow
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TESTE EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    #define TEST prefixX(2, simplePrefix, X, Y)
    static_assert(false, TESTE);

    return 0;
}
```

Static assert prints: `static assertion failed with "simplePrefixX, Y, simplePrefix"`

My expected result is `simplePrefixX, simplePrefixY` 
Is there a way to force variadic macro to provide proper input?

I can use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 for this project

Comment: You might consider using `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD` so you don't have to pass the count to `prefixX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

```
#define prefix2(pefixV, a1, a2) pefixV##a1, pefixV##a2
#define prefix3(pefixV, a1, a2, a3) prefix2(pefixV, x, y)##, ##pefixV##z

#define macroMagic(x) x

#define prefixX(count, pefixV, ...) macroMagic(prefix##count(pefixV, __VA_ARGS__))

//MacroTester from stackoverflow
#define QUOTE(str) #str
#define EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(str) QUOTE(str)
#define TESTE EXPAND_AND_QUOTE(TEST)

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    #define TEST prefixX(2, simplePrefix, X, Y)
    static_assert(false, TESTE);

    return 0;
}
```

It works because `macroMagic` is invoked before `prefix##count` and it changes `__VA_ARGS__` from `X, Y` interpreted as one inseperable element to `X`, `Y` as seperate element.